# Done - Spring Security JWT Token_Key

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I have a problem with Spring Security / Boot (1.2.5) and JWT.

First of all I have a running Auth-Server which use JWT. I could already test it and enabled the /oauth/token_key resource.

```
# curl -u client_id:client_secret http://localhost:8080/oauth/token_key
{"alg":"SHA256withRSA","value":"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiGB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"}
```

In the documentation of spring boot "28.1.2 Resource Server" (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-security.html) there is an configuration entry called: "security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri". With that it should be possible to load the public key from the given uri. Independent of what I enter there, the result is always the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChainRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.servlet.Filter]: : Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: : Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=security, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=security, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setAuthenticationConfiguration(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.setGlobalAuthenticationConfigurers(java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springBootAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: : Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=security, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties': Could not bind properties to [unknown] (target=security, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Bean property 'oauth2[client][accessTokenUri]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:234)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:221)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any Ideas?

Best regards,
Stack

Comment: That is for Spring Boot 1.3 not 1.2... Oath2 auto config support was added in 1.3. Either update or find another way.

Comment: Oh you're totally right. I will use the M2. Sorry for the stupid question. Totally missed that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) already told in his answer, OAuth2 auto configuration support was only added in [version 1.3 of Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3.0-M1-Release-Notes) and thus you need to update it to be able to use it.